# Ideal in ring of polynomials with complex coeffeicnts

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for help on this problem

:[image]

Our definition of an Ideal I, of a commutative ring R , is a subset of R such that

$0 \in I$,

$s,t \in I \to s+t \in I$

and for all $s \in I$, any $r \in R, sr=rs \in I$

My thoughts for this question:

(a) This option seems wrong as it would be easy to see our third condition not violated.

But b , c and d all seem very similar to me. I am having trouble noticing whatever the differences are. I know this is a principal ideal ring too. I would think maybe I could rule out b as we could multiply by complex coeffiecnts and then we would be in the ideal violating the third requirement.

but for c and d, I am not sure. How would different coeffiecnts adding to zero or not change things?

Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For c), note that this set is the kernel of $\Bbb{C}[x]\to \Bbb{C}:p\mapsto p(1)$.

For d), note that $x-1$ is in this set. Is $(x-1)(x+1)$ in this set?

For a) and b), your arguments are correct.

Comment: Hm I'm not sure, for d maybe not because wouldn't x^{2}-1 might not satisfy conditions if a2=2 , a1=0 and ao=0 ?

Comment: Hello? Im not sure what it will mean?

Comment: Yes that's right. $x^2-1=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ where  $a_2+a_1=1$.

Comment: Thank you, so it will be c then?

Comment: Yes, since none of the others are ideals.